# How does java locate a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

The JAR file locates at `C:\Workbench\jars\antlr-4.4-complete.jar`

The environment variables are:

```
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Workbench\jars\*
PATH=C:\Workbench\jars;...
```

I am trying with the following commands:

```
java -jar "C:\Workbench\jars\antlr-4.4-complete.jar"   <-- OK
java -jar antlr-4.4-complete.jar   <-- FAIL!
java org.antlr.v4.Tool  <-- OK
```

I am totally confused about the failed one. I am expecting the `PATH` variable will be looped through to locate the jar file. But it seems not. Why?

My guess is, the implementation of `java -jar` command line doesn't use the `PATH` variable for searching jar file. But still, why?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of many of those over there -->

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` is for looking up the command to execute, in this case `java` will be looked up on the `PATH`.

You will need to supply either an absolute or relative path to `java -jar` because the terminal (bash/windows/zsh/etc...) will not expand arguments in this way. `CLASSPATH` is used by Java to look up further jars, but it expects a correct path to the initial jar as the first argument.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that I am using Windows. But it seems to coincide with my guess.